Mixed conditional 1 and 2
1 I can do that If you came
2 I could do that If you came
3 I may do that If you came
4 I might do that if you came
2 and 4 are examples of so-called second conditional. 1 and 3 are corret too and are exsmples of mixed conditionals 1 and 2. Correct?

I wouldn't accept #1 or #3 with any meaning, and I can't think of many contexts where I wouldn't prefer ...If you come for #2 and #4. To my ear, the only difference is Past Tense came implies lower likelihood (further away from current / expected reality) than Present Tense  come - in context, making it a bit obsequious / wheedling.

@FumbleFingers. What's wrong woth 1 and 3. Let me give you an example "If you  stained my dress I will kill you" . I don't know if you did but this what happens if you did

TimR said can't relies on reality and can't be used with anything less firm like a hypothetical. Same for can, obviously. That's why #1 & #3 don't work, but the stained dress example is fine. Well, not really. This is a bit of a waste of time, though. Some of your random permutations of verb forms will be potentially valid, perhaps in contexts that no-one thinks of initially. Start with what you want to mean, not  What (if anything) could this mean?

To me, can do and may do imply future possibilities, so they don't make sense with came.

@KateBunting. "If you came" I don't know if you really did so  "I can help with anything" meaning that's what I can do in the future if you did something earlier in the past here came. Why not?

I can't imagine a context in which anyone would say that. I agree with FumbleFingers' last comment!
